# Overflowing div

Tags: css, coverflow

I can't seem to figure this out.

I have the following code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="schedule">//blah</div>
    <div class="schedule">//blah</div>
    <div class="schedule">//blah</div>
    <div class="schedule">//blah</div>
    //
</div>
```

I want the div #wrapper to of fixed width. And I want each .schedule to be also of a fixed width. I then want, it I have too many in the div, I could just scroll left and right inside that page.

I can't do this!! No matter what I try, when I add more .schedule, they pop to the bottom of the page, and start filling the next row!

Cheers
Kousha

EDIT: Thank you. All the results work. EXCEPT I need to be able to use float: left; or something so that all divs are stock to each other! How can I do that?

Comment: `overflow-x:scroll` have you tried this?

Comment: Which combinations of css did you try?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#wrapper .schedule {
    display: inline-block;     
    padding: 5px;        
}
```

I've put together a basic [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/xsgXs/1/).

Answer (score 1):

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/JkBLCZO9)***

Hi now used to this css

```
#wrapper{
min-width:200px;
  background:red;
  font-size:0;
  white-space:nowrap;

}
.schedule{
height:100px;
  font-size:12px;
  width:100px;
  background:green;
  margin:1px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/JkBLCZO9)***

Now change to width or height according your layout .........

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want is the schedule-divs to float to align themself on the same height.

Try adding this to your css:

```
 #wrapper{overflow:auto;}

.schedule{float:left;}
```

Sorry if I missunderstod your specification, but I think that's what you really want.